# Shell Script execution

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a shell script, Script is working as expected. I did not understand why in some servers it is working without giving this command `./script.sh` start. Is there anything at the server side configuration I need to change?

```sh
$HOME/soa_config.ini
$HOME/.credentials > /dev/null 2>&1
```

```sh
$HOME/soa_config.ini
$HOME/.credentials > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56755180/edit) to include more information.

Comment: I have a hard time wrapping my head around your second sentence, care to rephrase it?

Comment: How to execute the shell script without using ./ or sh ?

Comment: `./script` vs `script` : the second one is possible when script is inside one of the directories listed by the `$PATH` variable. Some servers might have `.` inside the `$PATH`, which will let you call any script of the current directory without having to use its relative path `./script`

Comment: About `sh`, I'm not sure whether you're talking about invoking a script with `sh script` or invoking a script named `script.sh`. For the former, avoid using `sh script`, instead make sure the file is flagged as executable and call `script` directly. For the later, the `.sh` extension is just there for human readability, you can call your `script.sh` script `script` and it'll just work as well as before.

Comment: Executing programs as `./script` is the way to go. Adding `.` to your `PATH` is discouraged mainly because of the security implications (overriding even standard commands with executables in the working directory if you put `.` at the beginning – don't do that).